# What type of magnetic fields does a Hall effect semi-conductor pick up on?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

What type of magnetic fields does a Hall effect semi-conductor pick up on? AC or DC fields? How would one go about building a device that measures AC Magnetic fields?

Answer (score 1):

Hall effect devices measure the instantaneous magnetic field in a particular direction.  There is no lower frequency limit.

Measuring AC magnetic fields is easier since some methods inherently react to the change in the magnetic field.  Of course you could just high pass filter the output of a Hall sensor, but there are other ways too.

The simplest way to sense changing magnetic fields is probably a coil.  The open circuit voltage from the coil will be proportional to the derivative of the magnetic field in the direction thru the loop of the coil.  More turns makes the output proportionally stronger.

A product I once worked on used a more exotic method, which was a piezo element mechanically bound to some magneto-restrictive material.  A change in the magnetic field would change the dimensions of the magneto-restrictive material, which would induce the piezo element to create a voltage.

Comment: What's the math to get a Tesla reading based on the output of the coil? Is it that simple?

Comment: Also, there are many 3 axis AC Gaussmeters on the market. What does the 3 axis sensor used vaguely look like?

Comment: @user27930 Fundamentally to understand "the math" you must understand the physics of how the device works, however with most packaged instruments the manufacturer has done the heavy lifting for you: you just have to read the products documentation (often called a data-sheet).

Comment: 3-axis is usualy done with three one-axis sensors positioned orthagonally.